# How to check whether a value is fall into a range or not in clojure

Tags: clojure

The range could be defined by maxInclude, maxExclude,minInclude,minExclude

```
(defn check-range [value maxInclude maxExclude minInclude minExclude] ...)
```

And the following should hold true.

```
(check-range 100 100 nil nil 10) ;; should return true since 100<=100 and 100>10
(check-range 100 nil 200 nil 10) ;; should return true since 100<200 and 100>10
(check-range 100 100 nil 101 nil) ;; should return false since 100<=101 is not true
```

Is there any simple solution? I am using a long code which looks like imperative solution. I think in clojure there must be some nice solutions.

update: my code is as below, but not complete and need help to complete it

```
(defn check-range [value maxInclude maxExclude minInclude minExclude]
  ( 
   let [value1 (if (and maxInclude (< value maxInclude)) false true)
               value2 (if (and maxExclude (<=  value maxExclude)) false true)
               value3 (if (and minInclude (> value minInclude)) false true)
               value4 (if (and minExclude (>=  value minExclude)) false true)
               ]
         ;;; then how to combine value1,2,3,4 into final result as false or true.
     )
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what it means for a range to have *both* an inclusive and exclusive maximum (or similarly, minimum). It seems like those options should be mutually exclusive, which suggests you shouldn't let clients opt into choosing both. Otherwise, how do you decide if it's more important for inclusion to win, or exclusion? The choice seems like it would have to be pretty arbitrary.

I suggest that it would be better to have a different way of constructing the range. This would have the additional benefit of avoiding all the `nil` hoops you're talking about jumping through and let users be explicit about the kind of range that they're making.

Perhaps something like:

```
(defn make-range-checker [bottom-check top-check] 
  (fn [n]
    (and (bottom-check n)
         (top-check n))))
```

So that for your initial 3 examples, you'd do something like these to create range-checking functions that you could apply to your input of 100:

```
(make-range-checker (partial < 10) (partial >= 100))
(make-range-checker (partial < 10) (partial > 200))
(make-range-checker (partial <= 100) (partial > 101))
```

(your third example is not correct, incidentally: "100<=101 is not true")

Someone wanting to create a range that extends to infinity in either direction could simply pass a predicate that always returns true.

```
(make-range-checker (partial < 10) (constantly true))
(make-range-checker (constantly true) (partial > 10))
```